# Проверка состояния tcp соединения

Tags: erlang

Для проверки соединения используются heartbeat сообщения, получаемые
через heartbeat_interval. Если через заданный интервал новое heartbeat
сообщение не пришло - соединение потеряно. Для такой проверки написан
код, в котором мы получив heartbeat сообщение, увеличиваем счетчик на
1 и запускаем erlang:send_after/3 для обработки в handle_info/2.
Предполагается, что через 31 сек, то есть heartbeat + 1 сек, в handle_info/2
придет {check, Check_Num} и его придется сравнивать со следующим
сообщением.

```
handle_messages([{#heartbeat{msg_seq_num = Seq_Msg_Num},_}|Messages],#conn{heartbeatnum = Num} = Conn) ->
    H_B_Num = Num + 1,
    Check_Num = Num + 2,
    Check = erlang:send_after(31000, self(), {check, Check_Num}),
   handle_messages(Messages, Conn#conn{heartbeatnum = H_B_Num, check_seq_num = Check_Num, check = Check});
```

handle_info/2 имеет следующий код:

```
handle_info({check, Check_Num}, #conn{heartbeatnum = Heartbeat,check_seq_num = Num, check = Check} = Conn) ->
    if Check_Num > Heartbeat -> {ok, connection_up};
       true -> {disconnect, connection_down}
    end,
    erlang:cancel_timer(Check),
    {noreply, Conn#conn{check = undefined}};
```

В таком виде код работает не корректно, через раз
Что изменить или добавить, чтобы работал правильно?

**Обновление**

Строка

```
erlang:cancel_timer(Check)
```

в

```
handle_info/2
```

лишняя. Без нее работает правильно, но при компиляции все равно выдает

> Warning: a term is constructed, but never used.

Answer (score 1):

Ссылку на таймер надо удалять. Иначе они будут копиться и это ничего хорошего не принесет.
При разборе списка сообщений вы пишете в #state TimerRef, и каждый раз его переписываете. Тем самым теряете ссылки на таймеры. Наверно надо пересмотреть алгоритм.